# Streaming replication from PostgreSQL to MySQL/MemSQL

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, singlestore

I have two database systems currently in use in production: the main **PostgreSQL** database, and another database (**MemSQL**) used primarily for analytical purposes.

Is there a way to setup streaming replication of some of the tables in PostgreSQL to MemSQL (a MySQL-compatible database) rowstores, assuming the tables on both databases have the same schema?

Answer (score -1):

I do not think that there is a tool for that (yet) but there is one for limited MySQL to Postgres replication:
https://github.com/the4thdoctor/pg_chameleon
Maybe this can be adapted to work the other way.

And you could always build your own little data shovel by using the [NOTIFY/LISTEN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) feature of Postgres.
Which is probably only an option if you only have to copy a very simple set of data.

Comment: Using Logical Replication in PostgreSQL ( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/logical-replication.html ) you don't have to deploy Listen/Notify, but can just extract the real data changes from the WAL feed, and replicate them to MySQL.